# List: People Picker entries only from other list

Tags: list, people-picker, person-or-group

I'd like to have a list of active squads (**List A**) in our company. The list should be filled with the squad name and the members. The people picker field should only display employees, which are stored in a dynamic **List B**.

Is it somehow possible to limit the search on the people picker?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: @GaneshSanap SharePoint Online from M365 Enterprise.

Comment: Try workaround given below...you can use SharePoint group to limit users in people picker field.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using out of the box capabilities of SharePoint.

**Workarounds**:

1. **Limit employees using SharePoint group**:

   You can limit the employees shown in people picker field using SharePoint group like -

   Person or Group column settings:

   [image]
2. If you have stored the employee names in List B with (simple text or single value) columns which you can extend using lookup, you can use lookup column in List A instead of person or group column.

   Check supported column types in lookup at: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)